# Getting Cloud Run Rate exceeded error, when just two requests are being proceesed

Tags: concurrency, cloud, serverless, google-cloud-run

1. cloud Run is [configured](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency) with default concurrency 80 , so when I was testing two simultaneous connection, how can error "Rate exceeded" be thrown?
2. What happens if the number of requests exceed concurrency, suppose concurrency is set to two, then if third, fourth and fifth requests comes and first and second request has not finished, does these requests wait per Request timeout ? or not served at all ?

Comment: What's your max instance configuration? What's the cold start duration of your service?

Comment: The way to prevent this is to increase max instances as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#429).